# Ruby's @ sign methods

Tags: ruby

This feels like some magic is happening here.
Where can I find more info/documentation about the '@' sign method(s) ?

```
# https://ryanbigg.com/2019/03/ruby-trickery
def -@
  +self
end
```

Comment: And etc; also available on the web. It's just an unary operator--what specifically do you want to know?

Comment: I mean he did ask 'Where can I find more info/documentation about the '@' sign method(s) ?'

Comment: If you go to https://ruby-doc.org/core and start typing the method name in the "Methods filter..." box you can often get a good start on answers to this sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html

Summarising what's written there, operators are usually binary, however can be unary:

```
4 - 2
```

'-' is being used as a binary operator here - it operates on 2 variables

```
-4
```

'-' is now being used as an unary operator, and has a completely different meaning to when it is used as a binary.

Adding @ onto the end of a method definition tells ruby that it is an unary operator:

```
class MagicString < String
  def +@
    upcase
  end
end

str = MagicString.new("This is my string!")
+str => "THIS IS MY STRING!"
```

By adding the @ we tell ruby to only expect one variable to operate on (I guess you could call it one argument but that doesn't fit so well here)